# Java - Error in code connecting to a MYSQL database try/catch?

Tags: java, try-catch, identifier

I can't for the life of me figure out what the error in my code is. Anyone have any ideas? All the errors are coming in at catch statement about 5 lines from the bottom.

```
public void connectToDB(){
    try {
    // this will load the MySQL driver, each DB has its own driver
      Class.forName(dbDriver);
      // setup the connection with the DB.
      connect = DriverManager
          .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/?"
              + "user=root&password=");
    ResultSet resultSet = connect.getMetaData().getCatalogs();

    //iterate each catalog in the ResultSet
    while (resultSet.next()) {
      // Get the database name, which is at position 1
      String databaseName = resultSet.getString(1);
      if (databaseName.equals("Ballers")) {
          preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement("DROP DATABASE Ballers");
          preparedStatement.execute();
      }
    }
          ScriptRunner runner = new ScriptRunner(connect, false, false);
          try {
            runner.runScript(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dumpPath)));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("not connecting");
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The text of the errors are  as follows:

```
DatabaseHelper.java:64: <identifier> expected
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
                                       ^
DatabaseHelper.java:64: '{' expected
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
                                         ^
DatabaseHelper.java:64: not a statement
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
                                                       ^
DatabaseHelper.java:64: ';' expected
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
```

What identifier is expected? Is this not a valid statement?

Comment: You are messing with Java environment.check JRE setting. It will work fine if you using JDK7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have an odler version of Java

Multiple-exception catches are supported, starting in Java 7.You must catch them separately.

convert

```
} catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("not connecting");
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

to

```
} catch (ClassNotFoundException  e) {
        System.out.println("not connecting");
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch ( SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("not connecting");
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation of the problem and how to fix it if I had decided not to go to Java7.

Answer (score 1):

It is valid in [Java 7 and up to specify multiple exception types in a catch block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html) in this manner.  Because you got this error, you must be using a prior version of Java.

Comment: Thank you very much. I updated to Java7 update 65 and relaunched the compiler and it worked.